# Joke of borrows at 6, lends at 9, and leaves at 4

Tags: interest-rates

I’m reading J. Michael Steele’s “Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications”, in Ch 10 he mentioned

> We are all familiar with asymmetry in interest rates — witness the
> worn-out joke about the traditional banker who borrows at 6, lends at
> 9, and leaves at 4.

It does not ring a bell — what is the joke pls?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-6-3_Rule

Comment: Perhaps it should be described as a "story", a "saying" or a "quip" or "witticism" rather than a "joke". It was not side-splitingly funny, but it captured the perception that a job in Banking was easy, in a mildly amusing way.